# USB adapter connected but not showing no nearby networks

Tags: wireless, usb, adapter

I installed Ubuntu and i can connect to internet through my internal wifi but when i want to connect internet through USB adapter it showing connected but no internet networks are available I tried installing Drivers but it's not working.
enter image description here

[image]

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? Which drivers you tried to install?

Comment: I don't know of any alternative drivers for that USB since the kernel driver has been based on Larry Finger's github since July 2021

Comment: I HAVE UBUNTU 20.04 AND DRIVER WHICH I DOWNLOADED FROM GITHUB IS RealTek RTL8188eus WiFi driver